# How can I prevent RuntimeError("Unable to create a new session key.")?

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, memcached

A client's Django application is intermittently (about twice a day) throwing `RuntimeError("Unable to create a new session key.")`:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/decorators.py", line 17, in _checklogin
    if request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 9, in __get__
    request._cached_user = get_user(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 107, in get_user
    user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 47, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 195, in _get_session
    self._session_cache = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/cache.py", line 16, in load
    self.create()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/cache.py", line 33, in create
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to create a new session key.")
RuntimeError: Unable to create a new session key.
```

As you can see from the traceback, this happens deep in the bowels of `django.contrib.sessions` when using the cache session backend with the memcached cache backend.

A Django trac ticket (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14093) suggests changing the session key hash from MD5 to UUID4, but that's no help -- the problem is the network. I've observed (with tcpdump) that this exception can occur when the TCP connection from app server to memcache server times out due to packet loss.

We have two app servers and one memcached (1.4.2) server, all running in Amazon EC2. During periods of high demand, I've observed one app server exchanging 75,000 packets/second with the memcache server. During this period of high demand, I observed one SYN packet for a new memcache connection get lost, resulting in a python-memcache connection timeout (before the kernel even had a chance to retransmit) and a `RuntimeError`.

I'm at a loss for how to solve this. I'd like to tune Linux's TCP retransmit timer lower than three seconds, but it's not tunable. Failing that, I'd like to have python-memcache retry a connection a couple times before giving up, but it won't. I see that pylibmc has configurable connect and retry behavior, but I haven't been able to find a combination of options that works around the packet loss.

Ideas?

---

UPDATE:

For people who see "Unable to create a new session key" all the time, that just means your memcache is not set up correctly. Some of the answers below discuss things to check (is the package installed? is the port correct?).

The problem we were having was *intermittent* — only one in several thousand requests would fail. I used `tcpdump` to show that this happens when one of the three packets in the TCP three-way handshake is lost (due to network congestion), resulting in `python-memcache` timing out and raising an exception, resulting in the "Unable to create a new session key" `RuntimeError`.

Packet loss in cloud provider networks may be unavoidable. Ideally, the Linux kernel would make the TCP initial retransmit timer configurable, but that did not appear to be the case at the time I was investigating this. That means the `python-memcache` library itself would need to have some kind of timeout-and-retry logic, which it did not have (at the time).

It looks like later versions of Django's cache backend have added a retry loop, which should avoid these kinds of intermittent failures, at the expense of requests occasionally taking a few seconds longer.

Comment: I have the same problem with pure Django on dev-sever. Post please your settings.

Comment: Not exactly the answer you were looking for - but is redis an option? Especially for sessions, because Redis has disk based backup, where memcached if the service is restarted your users sessions are killed. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the python-memcached code on launchpad, you should be able to tweak `dead_retry` and `retry_timeout`. Another option may be to run a low memory, low connections instance of memcached on one or both of the app servers as a fallback when the primary memcached server is unreachable.

Comment: How did you solved this @claymation? Could you provide more details?

Answer (score 6):

Just solved same problem with `apt-get install memcached`. May be it's your case too.

Ou, sorry, this is not your case. I'vr just read question with more attention. But I will left my answer - cause it's about this runtime error.

Comment: Thanks, but running the cache locally on the app server (which is what I think you're suggesting) isn't an option here, because we have multiple app servers and want to share the cache among all the app servers.

Comment: @claymation, I have just told possible reason. Of course memcached can be on other server.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolay Fominyh

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/cache.py

```
def create(self):
    # Because a cache can fail silently (e.g. memcache), we don't know if
    # we are failing to create a new session because of a key collision or
    # because the cache is missing. So we try for a (large) number of times
    # and then raise an exception. That's the risk you shoulder if using
    # cache backing.
    for i in xrange(10000):
        self._session_key = self._get_new_session_key()
        try:
            self.save(must_create=True)
        except CreateError:
            continue
        self.modified = True
        return
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to create a new session key.")
```

- you can monkey-patch `django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase._get_new_session_key` to do a `time.sleep(0.001)`.
- you could also [check your entropy](http://rackerhacker.com/2007/07/01/check-available-entropy-in-linux/):

here's the command:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error running a local, development version of a Django project, because it was periodically having trouble connecting to a non-local cache. I [realized](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yabi-discuss/HerLYilIK2A) that I could change my session backend to [a file-based session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#using-file-based-sessions) to address the issue .

In the settings file for this local, development version of Django, I simply set the following value:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.file'
```

This is not the solution I would use in a production environment, and not the solution I would suggest to the original poster, but it took me a few minutes to figure out what the issue was and this is one of the only results that appeared when I Googled, so I figured I'd post here possibly to help out others with a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

In the memcache config file (*e.g.*, `/etc/sysconfig/memcached` or `/etc/memcached.conf`), you may need to change:

```
-l 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
-l 0.0.0.0
```

to allow the web server to connect to the memcache server (if they are on different hosts).

Comment: If _every_ request fails with "Unable to create a new session key", then this might be a problem, if the cache is running on a different host than the web server. But there are probably several other types of misconfiguration that can lead to the same error message. My post was about _intermittent_ errors that happen rarely (and seemingly randomly) despite everything being configured correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue I faced, Check ports configured in django and memcached.May be both are different.

you can change memcached port vim /etc/memcached.conf find 'Default connection port is' changed according to your need restart memcached services

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly CPU shortage. when the request goes to be completed watching  /var/log/apache/error.log could be the best place for monitoring. also take htop tp monitor your cpu while you are working with web console.
you should increase CPU cores